# How to calculate bias having three groups?

Tags: bias, group-differences

Three groups of people each tried one of the three different applications and answered a questionnaire on a Likert scale from 0 to 4. Their age and experience in video games were also asked (on a Likert scale). A Kruskal-Wallis analysis, to tests for significant differences in medians among groups was performed. Post-hoc tests using the Mann-Whitney U test were conducted to identify specific differences between groups, and a Bonferroni correction was applied to adjust the significance levels. How can I perform bias analysis?

Comment: What bias do you want to investigate? Why do you suspect bias?  Also, why not do ordinal logistic regression?

Comment: I would like to examine whether there are significant differences in age and gaming experience between the three groups that tried the different apps to see if there are any disparities that could skew the results of the study.

Regarding the suggestion to perform an ordinal logistic regression, I understand that this technique could be appropriate to explore the relationship between the predictor variables (such as age and video game experience) and the variable of interest (the application used). However, I seek to evaluate possible biases in the composition of the groups.

Comment: How did you construct these groups? If they were randomized correctly any apparent imbalance would simply be a sampling effect, so there is no use in testing for it.